# Calling a Java webservice from C# .NET Core (specifically Workday). How to get xml attributes in the soap request

Tags: c#, xml, soap, workday-api

I am trying to call Workday's web service in .net core c#. The service was written in Java. I'm having problems getting xml attributes to show up in my soap request.

Example: What I want it to look like:

```
...       
<wd:Usage_Data wd:Public="true">
    <wd:Type_Data wd:Primary="true">
        <wd:Type_Reference>
...
```

What it does look like:

```
...
<wd:Usage_Data>
   <wd:Type_Data>
      <wd:Type_Reference>
...
```

I cant get the `wd:Public="true"` to be there in the send request xml output. I am setting it in c#.

What I've done is create a WCF Service Reference to workday, and modified the Reference.cs to https://hr.dovetailsoftware.com/gcox/2014/06/13/getting-started-workday-web-services-using-c/, and tried playing around with the xml serializer a bit, but no luck. Other workday services that don't have any attributes work just fine.

I'm sure its a simple fix but I cant find it. I can post more code if necessary.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I think it's a Wrokday thing. Posting here in case of anyone else.  You actually need to set the "Specified" properties.

```
        phoneType.Usage_Data[0].Public = true; 
        //not good enough, you need to set this
        phoneType.Usage_Data[0].PublicSpecified = true;
```